# dba.BlogOverflow.com — migrate or freeze?

Tags: discussion, blogoverflow

Stack Exchange is going to be discontinuing the BlogOverflow.com website for community blogs.

We could migrate the few posts we had to another blogging platform, or (iiuc) it can just be converted to static pages in situ.

Answer (score 3):

Freeze.

I thought we could have a productive blog if content creation was familiar to site users and tied to the site, and if people didn't have to have yet another login to provide content — failing that I don't see a dba.se blog working on an external blogging platform any more than it did on blogoverflow.

There once was a plan to have an integrated blogging platform but I think that has been abandoned.